Need Advice: C# OOP Class (or Data) Relationship
I am working on my research project. Let say I have a steel bar with predefined length of 6 m. I installed 3 sensor at location 0m, 3m, and 6m. The steel bar will be subjected to several test conditions, let say condition A, B, C, D, etc. I need to create post-processing program to process this data.
(NB: This problem has been simplified, the actual problem is more complex and it will be confusing if I explain all the details)
What is the best way to establish the data relationship in here ?
Let say I have

Bar Condition: A, B, C, D
Temperature: (key value pair of position and its temperature)

It is better to create relationship of:
(SteelBar Has-A BarCondition)
    (BarCondition Has-A Temperature)
or it is better to create relationship of:
(SteelBar Has-A Temperature)
    (Temperature Has-A BarCondition)
?
Later on, I also need to create combination of the temperature at the same position. For example:

Combination 1: BarConditionA + BarConditionB
Combination 2: BarConditionC + BarConditionD
Combination 3: 30% * BarConditionC + 40% BarConditionD
... etc.

There will be around 1000 combinations, and there will be around 500 bar condition. And there will be more than 15 sensor position that measure its temperature. (And in real case, it not only measure the temperature but also some other data at the same position. Therefore I create class for that data itself)
Currently, I created a class named Temperature which stores the position and temperature data in a dictionary.
I also created a class named SteelBar which I will get the data
class Temperature
{
    private Dictionary<double, double> _temperatureData;
    public Dictionary<double, double> TemperatureData { get { return _temperatureData; } }
    public Temperature()
    {
        _temperatureData = new Dictionary<double, double>();
    }
    public void AddTemperature(double position, double temperatureinDegree)
    {
        _temperatureData.Add(position, temperatureinDegree); //
    }
}

class SteelBar
{
    private Temperature _BarTemperature1, _BarTemperature2;
    public SteelBar()
    {
        _BarTemperatureConditionA = new Temperature();
        _BarTemperatureConditionA.AddTemperature(0, 27);
        _BarTemperatureConditionA.AddTemperature(3, 39);
        _BarTemperatureConditionA.AddTemperature(6, 55);

        _BarTemperatureConditionB = new Temperature();
        _BarTemperatureConditionB.AddTemperature(0, 33);
        _BarTemperatureConditionB.AddTemperature(3, 99);
        _BarTemperatureConditionB.AddTemperature(6, 10);
    }
}

However I feel this approach is not correct. It will be problematic when I need to combine the temperature.

A measurement value seems to be identified by object under test, position and type (in this case temperature). And it has-a value. So you might create an id abstraction that let's you conveniently filter a described.

There are 2 questions come out in my mind after reading your question: 1. What data need to be established relationship? 2. Why do these data need to be established relationship?

It seems strange to me that this seems not to be aimed to resemble a database schema. A high volume of data that is going to be combined, filtered, etc pretty much describes an RDBMS.

Also, you are missing options: there is not only A has-a B or B has-a A. There is also C has-a A and a B.

I would create a SuperClass call Conditions to group similar object properties together
And then I will have many SubClass that inherits Conditions with properties set differently based on their respective individual Contexts. For instance TemperatureCondition Inherits Conditions
Then in your SteelBar class, you will have a List of Conditions, It doesnt matter what Conditions it is, you will just have 1 List
When you want to do whatever to your conditions, just loop through the list or find the item in the list based on their SubClass by using typeof(TemperatureCondition) for example
Searching can be made easily with Linq lambda expressions
